# Why is this linear programming request not working when iterated?

Tags: r, linear-programming

**PREFACE** This is a question about using linear modelling to understand an electricity generation system but you actually don't need to know very much of either to understand this. I'm pretty sure this is a question about R.

I am building a linear model to optimise the dispatch, hourly, of electric generators in a country (called "Lebanon" but actually it's a little fictitious in terms of the data I am using). I have a model which optimises the hourly generation satisfactorily, the code looks like the below:

```
lp.newobjfun.norelax <- lpSolve::lp(dir = "min", objfun.lebanon.postwalk1, constraintmatrix.lebanon.postwalk.allgenerators, directions.lebanon.postwalk3, rhs.lebanon.postwalk4)
```

The above works fine. Of course though, doing it per day is a bit useless, so instead I want to be able to run it iteratively every day for a year. The below code is supposed to do that, but instead the returned values (the objective function's value) is always 0. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
for(i in 1:365) 
{
rhs.lebanon.postwalk4[1:24] = as.numeric(supplylebanon2010wholeyear[i,])

lp.newobjfun.norelax <- lpSolve::lp(dir = "min", objfun.lebanon.postwalk1, constraintmatrix.lebanon.postwalk.allgenerators, directions.lebanon.postwalk3, rhs.lebanon.postwalk4)

print(lp.newobjfun.norelax$solution); 
}
```

Just to be clear, in the second version, the right hand side of the first 24 constraints are modified to relfect how the hourly supply of electricity changes each day of the year.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nevermind I've figured this out it's that there's a unit conversion from kWh to MWh which I hadn't taken care of.

Sorry for any bother!